# How to hide files and folders in PCManFM without changing their path?

Tags: lubuntu, paths, hidden-files, pcmanfm

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS and thus, use the PCManFM file manager. I want to hide some files and folders from the view that the file manager provides, but I can not use the `.`-prefix or any other solution that changes the path, because some programs rely on these paths.

The best option I could find is a solution via a file named `.hidden` containing the names of objects to be hidden, but this solution seems only to work with Nautilus - I tried it myself with PCManFM and it did not change anything.

Is there an equivalent or similar solution for PCManFM?

Sidenote: I would prefer if the objects made hidden with whatever solution can still be made visible by the "show hidden" view. I also want to point out, due to what I have read in similar questions, that I want to hide these objects solely for the sake of tidiness and not for any obscure idea of security.

Comment: "but this solution seems only to work with Nautilus ". Nope. Works in Nautilus, Nemo, Caja and Thunar. I would say: file a bug report/feature request. `pcmanfm-mod` let you use user-defined command so you where able to do this but has been discontinued.